# Srcset not working but shows alt tag message

Tags: responsive-design, responsive-images, srcset

I am building a new website, and want to use the srcset to let the browser deside what image is the best for the current viewport.

What happens is that what ever i put in the srcset the browser will just show the alt tag text "test". If i through F12 developer tools removes the srcset attribute completely, the image shows up just fine.
All images in my example exists and shows up in a browser:

Here is my image tag, can any one see what is wrong with that?

```
<img src="http://localhost/Medium/Alaska-2-1818.jpg" srcset="http://localhost/Large/Alaska-2-1818.jpg 500w, http://localhost/XXLarge/Alaska-2-1818.jpg 1000w" alt="test">
```

---

My problem is shown in this codepen i made:
https://codepen.io/AxelAndersen/project/editor/DxKeaV

Answer (score 0):

In your Codepen, some URLs have an error, missing one "i".

Comment: Yes, that was a different mistake, its fixed now. 
Unfortunately that is not the case for my actual project. If I replace my localhost images with images.friliv.dk images it will work, is there something preventing this from working with localhost served images. I have a screen shot here showing my issue:
https://imgur.com/a/TJpzX

Comment: Your code misses the mandatory `src` attribute, maybe adding it will fix the issue. But I don't know why it works with remote images.

Comment: ehhh no: src="http://localhost/Medium/Alaska-2-1818.jpg"
And that should not be nessacary at all for modern browsers

Comment: Sorry, the code in the Codepen misses the `src`, but not the one in your question here. But, `src` is mandatory per specification, even if browsers deal with it when it's missing. So, if you're ok, I will delete my "answer" which answers nothing, and these comments… :-/